# trying to import a file

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm a beginner in php, I'm trying to use a library but I'm facing an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Einenlum\LingueeApi\Factory' not
>   found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 4

[the library is this](https://github.com/Einenlum/linguee-api)

I followed correctly what it says in the readme file
my code is like this:

```
<?php
use Einenlum\LingueeApi\Factory;

$linguee = Factory::create();

$response = $linguee->translate('desert', 'eng', 'ger');

echo $response->toJson();
?>
```

I'm not sure if this readme file is giving me correct information, how can I run this project?
[image][image: enter image descriptiodddddn here]

Comment: Are you using a framework that loads composers autoload or is this a single php file?

Comment: No, I did nothing other than install the composer and run the commands described in the readme file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that library/package is managed via `composer` you'd need to use `composer`'s autoload:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Einenlum\LingueeApi\Factory;
...
```

Find more information at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: This worked, thank you very much, can you tell me some material to study this?

Comment: Glad it works. There's more information on that link in my answer, the whole documentation for `composer` is available at https://getcomposer.org/doc/

Answer (score 0):

You should download the library and put in C:\xampp\htdocs\ to have the following path C:\xampp\htdocs\Einenlum\LingueeApi\Factory and set file permission to read, write and execute

## update 1

To use library inside vendor folder you should specify that in your path

```
 use vendor\Einenlum\LingueeApi\Factory;
```

Comment: I have htdocs\Einenlum......
If I put Einenlum in the htdocs folder, should it work?

Comment: Yes, inside htdcos folder I have the index file and the vendor folder and inside vendor folder I have the Einenlum folder

Comment: This library is using `composer`, no need to put it in `htdocs` folder

Comment: so you should modify your code with the correct path 



"use vendor\Einenlum\LingueeApi\Factory;"

Comment: I already tried this ...
one thing I noticed is that the folder is called linguee-api instead of lingueeApi, is that correct? I'm just following what it says in the readme file, I'm very new to it.